# What would happen if a Type 1 superconducting sphere was placed over the north pole of a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, superconductivity

This is a bit of a thought experiment but I thought it was rather interesting. I was doing research on superconductivity of Type 1 materials and how they repel magnetic flux due to the Meissner effect.

**Experiment:** If you had a Type 1 superconducting sphere (that is below it's critical temperature) with a hole in the bottom [Fig. A] and you inserted the north pole of a cylindrical magnet, what would happen to the magnetic field lines *inside* the super conducting sphere [Fig. B]? This is assuming there is no space between the magnet and the sphere once its inserted (ie. tight seal).

**My understanding:** The magnetic fields originating from the magnet in [Fig. B] would cause interesting induced currents on the inside of the sphere which would "cancel" the applied fields from the magnet. This would cause the fields within the sphere to "compress" / change direction within the sphere as seen by the green lines in [Fig. B] (the exact path they take, I have no idea).

This is also assuming that the south pole of the magnet would not have an impact on the inside of the sphere in [Fig. B] because any magnetic force applied to the outside of the field would also be repelled.

**Additional questions:**

- Is my understanding even close to correct? :)
- Would the total magnetic flux within the sphere continue to increase until the sphere returns to its normal resistive state?
- If you are all not fans of hypothetical questions, can you recommend a resource to learn more?

[image]